# Java regex can't work,but javascript can work

Tags: java, javascript, regex

My java regex is

```
Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("^((?:[^\\n]+\\n?)+)\\n*");
String a = "# clj-markdown\n\nA Clojure library designed to ... well, that part is up to you.\n\n## Usage\nFIX==ME==\n\n## License\n\nCopyright © 2015 FIXME\n\nDistributed under the Eclipse Public License either version 1.0 or (at\nyour option) any later version.\n";
System.out.print(compile.matcher(a));
System.out.print(compile.matcher(a).matches());
```

this output false,but I test in javascript can pass.

```
/^((?:[^\n]+\n?)+)\n*/.text(b)
```

how to resolve this problem?

may be this is java regex difference of javascript regex.

Comment: Try with `Pattern.DOTALL` -- not sure if that will work.

Comment: @Jongware it won't help since there isn't a dot in the op's regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the in-between `\n?` to `\n*`, since `\n?` matches an optional newline character where `\n*` matches zero or more newline characters.

```
String a = "# clj-markdown\n\nA Clojure";
System.out.print(a.matches("^((?:[^\\n]+\\n*)+)\\n*"));
```

The part where your regex `^((?:[^\\n]+\\n?)+)\\n*` fails is `markdown\n\nA` substring. ie, because of `\n\n` two newline characters.

`(?:[^\\n]+\\n?)` matches upto the `markdown\n`, and the next character in the input string is a newline character , when you make this regex to repeat one or more times `(?:[^\\n]+\\n?)+`  it would expect any character but not of `\n` immediately after matching the optional newline character. But there is a newline character following , so this makes the regex to fail.

`matches` method in java returns true only if the given regex matches the whole input string.

But `test` function in javascript will return `true`  if the regex given matches  from the start (*partial or fullmatch but it must be from the start*). It won't except full string match.

**Example:**

```
> /^[^\n]+\n/.test('foo\n\nbarbuz')
true
> /^[^\n]+\n/.test('\n')
false
```

Comment: Thanks,good job.but,you know why javascript can pass this regex.